# Why does Selenium not find an array-indexed XPath-based element when using Page Factory?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I have a POM (page object model) that has the following declaration:

```
public class MyPOM
{
 [FindsBy(How=How.XPath, Using="(//textarea)[0]")]
 private IWebElement questionDescription;

 //This fails too in Selenium, but successful in Chrome-console:
 [FindsBy(How=How.XPath, Using="(//input[@class='cso-num'])[0]")]
 private IWebElement questionScore;

 public MyPOM(IWebDriver driver)
 { 
    PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this)
 }

}
```

On my Chrome console, a `$x("//textarea")[0]` query fires up just fine. However, each of my XPath selectors which has such "array based indexing" results in a `NoSuchElementException`. I'm not sure what the problem is. Every validation of the XPath, outside of Selenium seems to return the valid HTML DOM node, but not so with Selenium.

I even added an explicit pause, prior to finding the element on the page as follows but to no avail:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

However, if I were to do the following in some method, it works fine:

```
IWebElement questionDescription = GetDriver().FindElements(By.XPath(".//textarea"))[0];
questionDescription.Clear();
questionDescription.SendKeys(description);
```

Is there a limitation to using array-based indexing when using XPath and PageFactory?

**Reason for using XPath**: Most of the HTML is autogenerated by an underlying framework which the developers have no access to or control over (rather unfortunate). The best way to have reliable and non-brittle tests is to use XPaths.

**UPDATE/SOLUTION:** This was the dumbest *Gotcha* ever! XPath indexes from 1 and not 0! However, before I could delete this question, an answer was already posted. I'm leaving the resolution in place of posting a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I had first set up my Selenium tests I had a similar issue. Try using something like:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It should go after you initialize your driver. I tried doing seperate waits for each time I loaded a page but they didn't work for me either. 5 seconds seems to be enough time for the platform I am developing for, but can be adjusted as needed.

Note that the code snippet may be different in C#. This came from Java program.

Answer (score 0):

You are using XPath and xpath index start from 1. so your xpath should be (//textarea)[1] in place of (//textarea)[0] if you are trying to find first element.